# Is there a python module for lsof?

Tags: apt, python, lsof

Each time I try to update my Kali Linux by running

```
sudo apt update
```

I get the following error message

```
Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

The way I fix this problem is by finding processes by running

```
lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
lsof /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
lsof /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

and killing the processes that have acquired the locks.

I  would like to automate the process.

Answer (score 4):

#### The answer to the question you should have asked

**This is not a good idea**. You should not kill processes blindly. Find out which process has the file locked and why.

Furthermore, if you're having this problem often, you're probably doing something wrong. Kali Linux is a special-purpose distribution for penetration testing. It is not designed to be installed. **[To do anything other than penetration testing, do not use Kali](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux)**. Use a normal distribution such as Ubuntu.

#### How to find a process that has a file open in Python

You can use the [`psutil`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package to enumerate processes and enumerate the files that they have open. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106220/check-for-open-files-with-python-in-linux has a code example.

To just enumerate processes that have a file open, it may be easier to parse the output of [`fuser`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fuser.1.html).

```python
import os, subprocess
try:
    pids = subprocess.check_output(['fuser', '--', filename], stdout=open(os.devnull))
    for pid in map(int, pids.split()):
       print('Process {} has {} open'.format(pid, filename))
```

Answer (score 3):

> Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

`apt` provide  `apt-daily-upgrade.service` and `apt-daily.service` services , when enabled the `apt` will be executed in background. see `systemctl list-timers`

to disable it :

```
systemctl disable apt-daily.timer
systemctl disable apt-daily.service
systemctl disable apt-daily-upgrade.timer
systemctl disable apt-daily-upgrade.service
```

Debian: [UnattendedUpgrades](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades)